# Priview selected text value from a dropdown list with php

Tags: php

halooo..

i'm still new with php and got headach on this problem;

How do I get the selected text value from a dropdown list in php. i give sample for detail

1. file name test.php

Code:

```
  <select name="trancode" size="1" id="select">
    <option value="309 ">309 - Book</option>
    <option value="207">207 - Magazine</option>
    </select>
```

1. preview.php

Code:

when run preview.php, output was refer to option value..how to display the text ?

eg : if choose 207 - Magazine, the result should '207 - Magazine' and not '207' only which is refer to option value..

fyi, the code 207 is referred to the price, eg, $207 x 2 units..

pls guide

Comment: The selected value is always sent to PHP, you can't do it, you need to write that text in value="your text"...

Comment: If you need to get the "text only" avoid the value attribute <option>207 - Magazine</option>

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the "text only" you could use

```
<select name="trancode" size="1" id="select">
    <option>309 - Book</option>
    <option>207 - Magazine</option>
</select>
```

And display the text using $_POST['trancode'] or $_GET['trancode'];

Edit:

If you need to extract the digit from the text for further calculation you can use the following:

```
$text=$_POST['trancode'];
if(preg_match('/(\d)+(?=(.)*-)/',$text,$matches))
{
    $value=$matches[0];
}
else
{
    $value=null;
}
```

So you could get see the text as 309 - Book and extract the value as 309 for calculation.

Comment: thanks john for the feedback..mayb i should add more detail on my case as above

Comment: @rem: if you have to use the value to you can use the preg_match function to fetch the number(value) like 207 from the text.

Comment: hi john, blurr...hehe..can u detail it more..not at that level at the moment..hehe

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to put the actual text in value attribute.

```
<select name="tranode" size="1" id="select">
<option value="309 - Book">309 - Book</option>
<option value="207 - Magazine">207 - Magazine</option>
</select>
```

This is probably not the best way, but it is a fix if you absolutely have to use the Value attribute

Comment: thanks william.. that is what i've done before, but when come to calculation, still got problem coz i prefered that opt value as a number, in other word easy to me to count on the later script..eg: 2 units book x $309 = $618 ..

Comment: I see what you're saying using the value to do the calculations. I can see 2 possible solutions. 1. You can use it like this and extract the number from the string using preg_match_all expression or you could substring it. Assuming the first part is always going to be the price. Off the top of my head: $price = substr($value,0,strrpos('-')-1)

Comment: i added detail for this script;
<select name="unit" size="1" id="select2">
    <option value="1">1 Unit</option>
    <option value="2">2 Units</option>
    <option value="3">3 Units</option>
    </select>
------display.php----
<?php 
 $trancode = $_POST['trancode']; 
 $unit = $_POST['unit'];
 $total = $trancode * $unit;
 
 print "$total";
?>